# how to access _selectedRoute leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

how can I access this `_selectedRoute` in my code? i need it to save instructions and summary

```js
let routing = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(20.97912897266421, 105.78617941902107),
        L.latLng(21.0033696728394, 105.82059752419705)
    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
}).addTo(mymap);

console.log(routing)
console.log(routing._selectedRoute)
```

it said `undefined` when I `console.log` it, thank you

reference: [browser logs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL2nv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the route is an *asynchronous* operation, it will start when you create the routes control (or when waypoints are changed), but it will complete at some later point. This means that the route will not be available immediately after the control is created.

This is common in JavaScript, a lot of operations are asynchronous and you normally deal with it either by callbacks or event handlers, you should look into familiarizing yourself with this concept.

In this particular case, you should not use `_selectedRoute`, the underscore indicates it is an internal variable not intended for public use. Instead, you should use the `routeselected` event handler to perform whatever action you need when a route is selected:

```js
routing.on('routeselected', function(e) {
   var route = e.route
   // Your action goes here
})
```